# PHP - Checkbox and Implode

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes that are hidden and based on the selection, the checkbox will appear. However, when I `implode` the checkboxes, it returns multiple commas I was thinking of using `substr` and `if` `else` to remove the amount of comma based on the question selection. Here's my mark up

```
            <?php
              if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                $QuestionUsed = implode(',', $_POST['QuestionUsed']);
                $SolutionOffered = implode(',', $_POST['SolutionOffered']);
                echo $QuestionUsed;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $SolutionOffered;
              }
            ?>

              <form action="testing.php" method="post">
                <table class="table">
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Port-Out Reason</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <select id="portoutselector" name="PortOutQuestions" class="btn-block">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="PortOut1">Demande de numéro de compte</option>
                        <option value="PortOut2">Intérêt pour offre de la compétition</option>
                        <option value="PortOut3">Demande d’annulation sans vouloir donner une raison</option>
                        <option value="PortOut4">Plainte par rapport au réseau Rogers</option>
                        <option value="PortOut5">Déménagement à l’extérieur du réseau Rogers</option>
                        <option value="PortOut6">Déménagement à l’extérieur du pays</option>
                        <option value="PortOut7">Volonté de renégocier une offre existante au dossier ou de recevoir une offre additionnelle</option>
                        <option value="PortOut8">Déverrouillage d’appareil</option>
                      </select>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Questions utilisées?</th>
                  <tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="PortOut1 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="QuestionUsed[]">Pour quelles raisons désirez-vous cette information?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="QuestionUsed[]">Avez-vous besoin de cette information pour effectuer un paiement?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="QuestionUsed[]">Êtes-vous entrain vous inscrire à la facturation en ligne?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="QuestionUsed[]" id="otherbox01">Autres, spécifié:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other01" style="display:none" name="QuestionUsed[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut2 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="QuestionUsed[]">Quelles est l’offre que vous avez reçu d’un autre fournisseur?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="6" name="QuestionUsed[]">Quels sont  les détails de l’offre qui vous intéresse?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="QuestionUsed[]">Quel est le compétiteur qui vous intéresse?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="QuestionUsed[]">Quels sont vos besoins?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="9" name="QuestionUsed[]">Quel est votre budget mensuel consacré à vos services sans fil?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="10" name="QuestionUsed[]" id="otherbox02">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other02" style="display:none" name="QuestionUsed[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut3 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="11" name="QuestionUsed[]">Il y a-t-il une offre de la compétition qui vous intéresse ?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="12" name="QuestionUsed[]">Êtes-vous satisfait avec Rogers ? (oui/non) Pourquoi?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="13" name="QuestionUsed[]">Êtes-vous au courant de nos offres promotionnelles?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="14" name="QuestionUsed[]" id="otherbox03">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other03" style="display:none" name="QuestionUsed[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut4 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="15" name="QuestionUsed[]">Vous expérimentez cet inconvénient depuis quand?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="16" name="QuestionUsed[]">Ce problème arrive partout ou dans un endroit en particulier?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="17" name="QuestionUsed[]">Avez-vous déjà  discuté de cette situation avec le département technique?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="18" name="QuestionUsed[]" id="otherbox04">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other04" style="display:none" name="QuestionUsed[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut5 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="19" name="QuestionUsed[]">Dans quelle région déménagez-vous?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="20" name="QuestionUsed[]">Pour combien de temps pensez-vous demeurer à cette adresse?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="21" name="QuestionUsed[]">Comptez-vous réutiliser ce téléphone dans le futur?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="22" name="QuestionUsed[]">Est-ce que vous comptez avoir les services d’un autre fournisseur pendant cette période?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="23" name="QuestionUsed[]" id="otherbox05">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other05" style="display:none" name="QuestionUsed[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut6 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="24" name="QuestionUsed[]">Est-ce que le déménagement est pour une période limité (vacances, travail, etc.) ou pour une durée indéterminée?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="25" name="QuestionUsed[]">Considérez-vous revenir au pays dans le futur ?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="26" name="QuestionUsed[]">Est-ce que vous avez un membre de votre famille ou amis restant au pays qui pourrait utiliser votre appareil?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="27" name="QuestionUsed[]" id="otherbox06">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other06" style="display:none" name="QuestionUsed[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut7 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="28" name="QuestionUsed[]">Qu’est-ce-qui vous fait douter de l’offre initiale?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="28" name="QuestionUsed[]">Quel aspect de l’offre ne vous satisfait pas?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="30" name="QuestionUsed[]">Il y a t- il une offre de la compétition qui vous intéresse?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="31" name="QuestionUsed[]" id="otherbox07">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other07" style="display:none" name="QuestionUsed[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut8 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="32" name="QuestionUsed[]">Pour quelles raisons désirez-vous faire déverrouiller votre appareil?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="33" name="QuestionUsed[]">Êtes-vous satisfait avec votre appareil?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="34" name="QuestionUsed[]">Êtes-vous au courant de nos nouvelles offres?</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="35" name="QuestionUsed[]" id="otherbox08">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other08" style="display:none" name="QuestionUsed[]">
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Solutions offertes?</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="PortOut1 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="SolutionOffered[]">Réviser l’utilisation sans fil des 3 derniers mois et offrir la meilleure solution possible.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offert au client de l’inscrire à la facturation en ligne.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="SolutionOffered[]" id="otherbox11">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other11" style="display:none" name="SolutionOffered[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut2 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="SolutionOffered[]">Réviser l'utilisation des 3 derniers mois et lui offrir une offre rétention par rapport à ses besoins.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="SolutionOffered[]">Forfait Québec à 70$</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir des escomptes sur des plans sur le marché</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="6" name="SolutionOffered[]">Revendre son plan actuel (client possédant plan rétention ou plan promotionnel</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="SolutionOffered[]" id="otherbox12">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other12" style="display:none" name="SolutionOffered[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut3 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir au client de réviser son forfait.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="9" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir un offre de bonne foi (si demandé)</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="10" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir une offre de rétention selon ses besoins</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="11" name="SolutionOffered[]" id="otherbox13">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other13" style="display:none" name="SolutionOffered[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut4 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="12" name="SolutionOffered[]">Faire une résolution de problème avec le client.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="13" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir un OOW si nécessaire.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="14" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir un rehaussement d'appareil.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="15" name="SolutionOffered[]" id="otherbox14">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other14" style="display:none" name="SolutionOffered[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut5 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="16" name="SolutionOffered[]">Recommandez  un transfert de responsabilité.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="17" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir au client une suspension temporaire si nécessaire/offre de dernier recours.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="18" name="SolutionOffered[]" id="otherbox15">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other15" style="display:none" name="SolutionOffered[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut6 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="19" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir au client une suspension temporaire au dossier.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="20" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir au client 50% de rabais pour 6 mois ou 12 mois selon les cas</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="21" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir au client la meilleure offre possible selon son utilisation au cours des 3 dernier mois</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="22" name="SolutionOffered[]" id="otherbox16">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other16" style="display:none" name="SolutionOffered[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut7 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="23" name="SolutionOffered[]">Repositionner et revendre la valeur $$ de l’offre déjà présente au dossier.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="24" name="SolutionOffered[]">Faire une nouvelle offre lorsque les besoins du client sont différents du plan déjà offert.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="25" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir la migration vers Fido lorsque les conditions requises sont remplies.</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="26" name="SolutionOffered[]" id="otherbox17">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other17" style="display:none" name="SolutionOffered[]">
                      </div>
                      <div class="PortOut8 unselected" style="display:none">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="27" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrez au client un nouvel appareil (si la situation le demande).</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="28" name="SolutionOffered[]">Offrir offre au client la meilleure possible selon son utilisation au cours des 3 dernier mois</label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="29" name="SolutionOffered[]" id="otherbox18">Autres, spécifié :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Other18" style="display:none" name="SolutionOffered[]">
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>

                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
              </form>
```

Current results:

```
,5,6,,,,,,,
,3,4,,,,,,,
```

Expected results:

```
5,6
3,4
```

Comment: I suggest to have a look at "split"

Comment: What will split do exception re-splitting the imploded array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you do this with proper checks, like:

```
$QuestionUsed = isset($_POST['QuestionUsed']) && is_array($_POST['QuestionUsed']) ? $_POST['QuestionUsed'] : array();
$SolutionOffered = isset($_POST['SolutionOffered']) && is_array($_POST['SolutionOffered']) ? $_POST['SolutionOffered'] : array();

foreach ($QuestionUsed as $index => $question) {
    if (empty($question)) {
        unset($QuestionUsed[$index]);
    }
}

foreach ($SolutionOffered as $index => $solution) {
    if (empty($solution)) {
        unset($SolutionOffered[$index]);
    }
}

$QuestionUsed = implode(',', $QuestionUsed);
$SolutionOffered = implode(',', $SolutionOffered);
```

Refactored with a small function would be:

```
function getCommaSeparatedStringFromArray(array $data = array()) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }
    return implode(',', $data);
}

$QuestionUsed = isset($_POST['QuestionUsed']) && is_array($_POST['QuestionUsed']) ? $_POST['QuestionUsed'] : array();
$SolutionOffered = isset($_POST['SolutionOffered']) && is_array($_POST['SolutionOffered']) ? $_POST['SolutionOffered'] : array();

$QuestionUsed = getCommaSeparatedStringFromArray($QuestionUsed);
$SolutionOffered = getCommaSeparatedStringFromArray($SolutionOffered);
```

Comment: Nice, but since there are already two arrays in this question alone, you might wrap the checking and cleaning-up of the input to a function to eleminate half of this code, so you can write something like `$QuestionUsed = getCheckboxArray('QuestionUsed'); $SolutionOffered = getCheckboxArray('SolutionOffered');`

Comment: Yup, he can refactor as needed, it's just an example :)

Comment: neah, solution on its way :)

Comment: just added it, not much but should do it.

Comment: Very nice! It is exactly what I needed. The moment that @GolezTrol mentioned a function, I thought it was a good idea but you did before me hehe :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use trim to cut off extra comma's, like:

```
$QuestionUsed = trim(implode(',', $_POST['QuestionUsed']),',');
```

Comment: It won't remove the comma's in the middle if you would get `1,,,,6,`.

Comment: This could work too since there's no comma in the middle in this case but I prefer the answer posted above since it's a safer option.